# How to make two different layout to have same height?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-layout-weight

In My application XML layout, I have one Relativelayout, In which there are two linear Layout. Now I am doing the animation for that both layout. But because thera seems the height different I got some view problem.

So I want to make the same height of the both layout. Below is my XML file.

```
<!-- ============================================================= -->
            <!-- BOTTLE / PEN LAYOUT -->
            <!-- ============================================================= -->
            <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" >

                <RelativeLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent">
                    <!-- ============================================================= -->
                    <!-- PEN LAYOUT -->
                    <!-- ============================================================= -->
                    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:id="@+id/pen_layout">

                        <TextView
                            android:text="EF"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                            android:textSize="10sp"/>

                        <ImageView                 
                            android:id="@+id/save"                 
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"                 
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="right"   
                            android:src="@drawable/ink_pen"/>             

                        <TextView
                            android:text="F"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                            android:textSize="10sp"/>
                        <ImageView                 
                            android:id="@+id/save"                 
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"                 
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="right"   
                            android:src="@drawable/ink_pen"/>             

                        <TextView
                            android:text="BOLD"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                            android:textSize="10sp"/>
                        <ImageView                 
                            android:id="@+id/save"                 
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"                 
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="right"   
                            android:src="@drawable/ink_pen"/>             

                        <TextView
                            android:text="ITALIC"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                            android:textSize="10sp"/>
                        <ImageView                 
                            android:id="@+id/save"                 
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"                 
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="right"   
                            android:src="@drawable/ink_pen"/>

                    </LinearLayout> 

                    <!-- ============================================================= -->
                    <!-- BOTTLE LAYOUT -->
                    <!-- ============================================================= -->

                    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:weightSum="4" 
                        android:id="@+id/bottle_layout">

                        <!-- First Row Bottle -->
                        <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:weightSum="2">
                            <ImageView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/purple_bottle"/>
                            <ImageView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/red_bottle"/>
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <!-- Second Row Bottle -->              
                        <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:weightSum="2">
                            <ImageView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/gray_bottle"/>
                            <ImageView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/green_bottle"/>
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <!-- Third Row Bottle -->               
                        <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:weightSum="2">
                            <ImageView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/orange_bottle"/>
                            <ImageView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/blue_bottle"/>
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <!-- Forth Row Bottle -->               
                        <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:weightSum="2">
                            <ImageView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/black_bottle"/>
                            <ImageView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/white_bottle"/>
                        </LinearLayout>

                    </LinearLayout>
                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Use weight for the child layouts. layout_height='.5' for both and you will get equal heights.

Comment: Not related to your question, but can I suggest that for your Pen layout, instead of using textView and imageview together like you do, to use a Button with text and the image set as the buttons drawableLeft or drawableRight attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the containing RelativeLayout (since it is the only child of your root LinearLayout you don't strictly need it) or change it to a LinearLayout.

Then for both the Pen layout and the bottle layout, add the attribute android:layout_weight and set them both to 1.

Make sure that both the layouts have the height set to MATCH_PARENT

Now your two layouts should share the space equally between them, thus making them the same height.

To share the space equally between the children of the Pen and Bottle layouts, I suggest that you set the height of each child to WRAP_CONTENT and the layout_weight of each child to 1.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Will you please updated my code with your answer and put it here ?

Comment: Your answer seems to right. But i want to show the Animation on the Pen Layout and Bottle layout thats why i have added the relative layout.

Comment: Does it have to be a RelativeLayout for the animation to work? Would you explain why?

Comment: Ok. I have done it in LinearLayout and works as i want. Thanks.