# How to let the ImageView and the TextView the same height

Tags: android, layout

My layout have ImageView(iv) and TextView(tv).
I want to let the tv right of iv.
And the tv's height is same as iv's.
The tv Gravity set as CENTER_VERTICAL.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iv"
        android:text="TextView" android:gravity="center_vertical"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

How to arrive the goal?

Comment: Can you use LinearLayout instead of RelativeLayout, then you can use layout_weight parameter as 1 for both ImageView and TextView

Comment: How you will get same height both widgets? textview height depends on text size. We can get side by side only, we can't guarantee the heights as same.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

hi try this .....

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical" >

  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_title_home_demo" />

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/iv"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/iv"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iv"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="TextView" />

   </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to set the textview property to `android:layout_alignTop="@id/iv"` and `android:layout_alignBottom="@id/iv"`

Answer (score 1):

Well to get it to center vertically correct, you will need to remove the `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"` line from your TextView tag.

However, it sounds like you might be trying to make the text change its size to fit the entire height of the ImageView. This obviously won't solve that, but I wouldn't recommend doing that in the first place as it could result in some strange looking views.

Answer (score 1):

You can use distinct sizes by using

> android:layout_width="wrap_content"

and /or

> android:height="300dp"

(same for height). Also check margins and paddings.

If you need to be more dynamic, you might consider android:layout_weight i.e. for letting 2 buttons have equal width and fill the horizontal space of the parent view you would set:

> android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>
> android_layout:weight="0.5".

you can follow this link: [How to make two different layout to have same height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8295556/how-to-make-two-different-layout-to-have-same-height)