# equal width for overlaying TextView and ImageView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I've got a TextView (text) overlaying my ImageView (image). My Problem ist that they do not have the same width. In other words - I want the red areas to appear white:

[image]

Here is my layout file so far:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#FFFFFF" >
    
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    
     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Title"
        android:padding="10dp" 
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="#9988FF88"
        android:textColor="#000000"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I am quite new to android and tried to add different tags to the textview like android:layout_alignLeft="@id/image" which couldn't fix it and also tried to configure the layout_width settings, but this didn't help me either. Also this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8710045/3442129) couldn't solve it (I guess that is because of my android:layout_width="match_parent" in my ImageView). The solution was about adding these lines to the TextView:

```
android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/image"
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image"
```

I was also looking for programmatical solution, which also couldn't fix it:

```
image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
text.setWidth(image.getWidth());
```

Any ideas how to get rid of my red areas? Every idea will be appreciated and I would be happy about either an xml solution or a programmatical solution ! Thanks in advance :)

**EDIT**

I should specify that the image inside the ImageView does get replaced alot so that some images do fill the full horizontal screen in their width. So at some images there shall be a margin on the left and the right, but on others there shall not (in other words - the title shall always be as big as the image). (Btw: Thank you for your fast responses!)

**UPDATE**

I worked around this issue simply giving the header a white background color.

Comment: A solution could be: copy the top part of the image, cut the sky and fill the hole with your semitransparent turquoise color. Then set this second image (which has the semitransparent color and the white borders) as the background for your TextView.

Comment: Okay I understand what you mean, but the image can change a lot so I would have to cut the image quite often and actually I really like my transparent header ;) But thanks for that idea!

Comment: I added a BETTER solution as an answer. Key concept: remove the borders from the image and then simulate the borders using the margins in both the ImageView and The TextView, to match a perfect alignment.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_margin="26dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF" >

   <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" />

   <TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Title"
    android:padding="10dp" 
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="#9988FF88"
    android:textColor="#000000"/>

  </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This works, but it forces my image into a fix size. I would prefer a variable size of the image since it changes quite often, but thank you !

Comment: Pat, If you remove scaleType from ImageView then this will work for images of different sizes but it will not have exact width of TextView. Other way of doing it is remove scaleType, put your image in "android:src" attribute and put some color or commong image in "android:background" attribute. This will make your imageview with same width as TextView and can show images with different sizes

Answer (score 1):

The best solution I can think of is:

- Cut the white bourders out of your image (You will then set some Margins in yout ImageView, to simulate the borders)

Then, change your layout so:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    />
     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Title"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="#9988FF88"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Hi Golem, The white borders are not part of the image, it's the background color of my relative layout. The margins could work for a static image, but since mine might change and might vary in height and width this would not work for me. Nevertheless, thanks! +1

Answer (score 0):

Your imageview is set to match_parent but there are still white areas around imageview. Are you sure your image doesn't have white areas around it?

Also, try using fill_parent instead of match_parent.

Comment: `fill_parent` is **the same** as `match_parent`, but it has been **deprecated** since API level 8.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>



            <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="8">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Title"
                <!--android:padding="10dp" -->
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="#9988FF88"
                android:textColor="#000000"/>
            </RelativeLayout>



            <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: If i do this I get a margin on every border of my image so that it gets smaller in size and does not fit at the top of the screen...